# How to make file dialog work like most other programs?

Tags: file-browser

In most programs, any characters you type will filter the list of files, and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will open the selected file/directory. For example, if I wanted to navigate to `assets/models/terrain`, I could type `as<enter>mod<enter>ter<enter>`.

In more recent versions of Blender, the file dialog does not seem to work like this. Letter keys seem to map to shortcuts, for example, <kbd>b</kbd> will start a rectangular selection inside the file dialog rather than filtering to files starting with letter "b".

I've tried pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to start a search, but if I press, for example `<ctrl+f>as<enter>`, instead of opening the `assets` folder, it just leaves me in a state where `assets` is visible but not selected, and I can't type further.

I've tried <kbd>Tab</kbd> in the file path as well to complete path segments, but the first completion removes focus from the file path bar. For example, `as<tab>mod<tab>` will not autocomplete to `assets/models`, because the first tab removes focus from the file dialog, and the following keys are ignored.

Is there any way to make the file dialog work like other programs (and, if memory serves, how Blender's file dialog used to?)

Comment: Apparently I was wrong about older versions of blender behaving like this. I checked 2.79, 2.8, and 2.9, and all have similar behavior.

Comment: If there is a folder like "assets" and I type *as*+*TAB* in the file name input box at the bottom of the open file dialog then it automatically jumps into that folder. The focus is still in the input box and I can type the next folder's name. But the name is case-sensitive ("Asset" <-> "asset") and it must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be an add-on that did what you described according to this post: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1169/133552

They discuss and link to an add-on called "File Browser Search" that 404's and doesn't exist anymore. There are however many file sorting features included in the current version of blender that you may find useful:

[image]     [image]

Other than that there doesn't seem to be a tab search feature like you describe in the newer versions of Blender.